# Need a hand with a non-working JQuery function

Tags: jquery, forms, post, submit, hidden

My JQuery function is supposed to modify the value of a hidden form field and then submit the form. But it won't. Fiddle [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5g1s-s8vz).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    // when clicking the submit button
    $('.findme').click(function(){

        // Get the value of the clicked a tag
        var index = $(this).attr("id");

        // Strip out the prefix, leaving only the id
        var usethisID = index.substring(index.indexOf("_")+1 );
        alert('Value to post: ' + usethisID) ;

        // Make a hidden form field and set its value to usethisID
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        x.setAttribute("name", "xid");
        x.setAttribute("id", "xid");
        x.setAttribute("value", usethisID);

        // submit the form
        $('#fruitform').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show your form m8.

Comment: also - aren't you missing `appendChild` or similar - Where are you putting your `X`?

Comment: like `$('#fruitform').append(x).submit();`?

Comment: Yeah, I can see that the createElement is not specifically creating the hidden field in fruitform. But irrespective of that, it's just not submitting. Form code is at http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5g1s-s8vz

Answer (score 0):

Aha! It wouldn't post because my a tag's href attribute was empty....